# binding datagridview data to list

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to fill the list with datagridview data,

```
name  fathername
x     xa
y     ya
```

datagridview look something like above with column name 'name' and 'fathername'

now I need to fill the list

```
myList = New List(Of mydata)

Public Class mydata
   Public name As String
   Public fathername As String
End Class
```

can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim myList As List(Of mydata) = New List(Of mydata)
Dim newItem As mydata
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    newItem = New mydata()
    newItem.name = row.Cells("name").Value
    newItem.fathername = row.Cells("fathername").Value
    myList.Add(newItem)
Next
```